# Broadcast Receiver for sent messages in android

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, smsmanager

I'm developing an application and one critical functionality is to send text messages. I'm using android smsmanager on pre-kikcat devices and for kikcat and above i just sent an intent to default sms app. Everything works fine up to here. The only problem is that i want to be notified whether my message sent successfully or not.

Is there any way for getting message status in android like a broadcast receiver. I know i can use pending intents with sms manager (still not sure how!) but what about messages i passed to default sms app to sent? how can i be notified about status of those messages.

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sendTextMessage method of SMSManager class. While using this you can get the report of your message as an intent to verify it. Here is a [complete example](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/10/smsmessage-delivery-in-android-with.html#.VQD_w_yUf5M) for sending and receiving an intent for the same.